# Odoo assetsbundle use wrong site-packages folder

Tags: python-3.x, pip, odoo, windows-11, odoo-14

I have multiple python version to handle multiple version of odoo instances in my Windows 11 system. I am using debugger configuration in VS Code to handle the Python used for those instances.

When I run Odoo 14 with Python 3.8.10, there was no error shown. but when I open it in browser, the style is broken. I noticed this error in the terminal log:

```
WARNING v14c_pkj odoo.addons.base.models.assetsbundle: c:\users\fadyn\scoop\apps\python27\current\lib\site-packages\sassc.py:9: FutureWarning: The `sassc` entrypoint is deprecated, please use `pysassc`
```

When looking for the deprecated sassc issue, I learned that installing the `libsaas` package should solve the problem. I already have installed the package along with the other packages by using `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`. But, from the error above, it seems like my Odoo assetbundle is using the `libsaas` in the Python 2.7 `site-packages` instead of the one in Python 3.8 `site-packages`.

how to change the site-package used by odoo assetsbundle?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Odoo is using the correct Python environment (Python 3.8.10):

• Check that you have selected the correct Python interpreter in VS Code for your Odoo 14 project. Go to the bottom status bar in VS Code and click on the Python interpreter version to select the one associated with Python 3.8.10.

• If you're using a virtual environment for your Odoo instance, make sure to activate it before running Odoo, to ensure that the correct Python interpreter and dependencies are used.

```bash
# Activate the virtual environment
source venv/bin/activate  # On Windows, use 'venv\Scripts\activate'
```

• Check PATH Environment Variable (such as PATH and PYTHONPATH): Check that the directory containing Python 3.8.10 is included in your system's PATH environment variable.

• Check your workspace settings in VS Code to ensure they are not overriding the Python interpreter selection. You can do this by creating a .vscode/settings.json file in your project directory and specifying the Python interpreter there:

```json
{
    "python.pythonPath": "path-to-python38.exe"
}
```

If not already used, consider using **virtual environments** for your Odoo instances to isolate dependencies and prevent conflicts between Python versions.

If you no longer need the Python 2.7 SassC package, you can uninstall it to prevent any potential conflicts.

After activating your Python 3.8 environment, make sure to use the correct pip from that environment to install or upgrade the required packages:

```bash
pip3 install --upgrade libsass
pip3 install --upgrade sassc
```

Ensure that all required Python packages and dependencies are correctly installed in your Python 3.8.10 environment. Run `pip3 list` in your Python 3.8.10 environment to verify.